# Is it possible to write bigtable requests to a specific region?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

For a replicated bigtable table with two clusters one in region X and one in region Y, I assume requests near region X go to region X nodes and requests near region Y to go to region Y nodes.

But is it possible to target a specific region where the requests go - is it possible to have writes for example always go to region X?

The use case is that writes are critical whereas reads are not. Would like writes to go to region X and reads to go region Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target a particular cluster with an application profile with single cluster routing configured.

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/app-profiles#settings